# Etcd - Outdated index. How to read "X-Etcd-Index" from client

Tags: go, etcd

I am using github.com/coreos/etcd/client for communicating with etcd cloud, sometimes i am receiving 401 error "The event in requested index is outdated and cleared" , on server page there is a explanation why it happened and how it can be solved. Actually I want to implement the following scenario.

1. Get "key" and its modified index
2. do some job
3. start watching on "key" from modified index

this way I can be shure that all changes during 2 step will be also received. But Etcd saves only top N changes and sometimes I am receiving 401 error. Acording [docu](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/api.md) I can use "X-Etcd-Index" + 1 header from Get key request as modified index to watch.

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:2379/v2/keys/foo' -vv
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< X-Etcd-Cluster-Id: f63cd37d2ff4f650
< X-Etcd-Index: 17245
< X-Raft-Index: 2107637
< X-Raft-Term: 360
< Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 09:02:20 GMT
< Content-Length: 791
< ...
```

But I don't use direct http calls , only github.com/coreos/etcd/client. How can I get (and is it actually possible using api) a http header info on from get key request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `X-Etcd-Index` header corresponds to the [`Response.Index`](https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/etcd/client#Response) field.

Answer (score 1):

The index is available in the response field as the "Index" object. See the documentation here: https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/etcd/client#Response